# Server went down while uninstalling a module; now I cannot install or uninstall the module

Tags: 10

I am unable to remove the ECA Core module on my Drupal 10.1 site due to the below error.

> Core module for ECA framework.
> The following reason prevents ECA Core from being uninstalled: Required by: eca_user

Unfortunately while I was initially removing the ECA User module, my host/server crashed and this is where I am at once everything came back up.  I can select the ECA User module to re-enable, however the screen refreshes and it does not re-install, nor is there any message on top of the screen of the ECA User module being enabled.  The module is not listed on the uninstall screen as an option.

I am now stuck in this limbo situation. I assume I need to go somewhere in the database and make some changes. I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Can you roll back to a previous backup before ECA was installed?  [That is what an ECA maintainer recommends, noting the module has decided to prioritize performance over uninstallability.](https://www.drupal.org/project/eca/issues/3262400#comment-14404107)

Comment: Thank you, yes that is something I will probably end up doing.